# Video loop plays in localhost not in server

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mozilla

I have a video in my page and I called it like

```
<video width="100%" autoplay='true' loop>
  <source src="img/Jolly.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="img/Jolly.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

It is not working recently.
In Chrome Browser console it shows that

```
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
```

In mozilla console it shows

```
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

But when I downloaded the code and tested in localhost it works fine. I already checked the answer regarding this error but it doesn't helps.So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be  IIS5 issue
I think it is required to add new MIME type to IIS server during site setup.

- IIS
- MIME Types

  Confirm there is no entry for the video file type
  then add
- List item

"mp4"/"video/m4".

If this is not case, you might need to add on `.htaccess`. Do something like below

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Comment: So I need to add an .htaccess file with this line in my root folder ?

Comment: Yes, Please try with that.